# Show custom default avatar instead of gravatar

Tags: php, functions, avatar, gravatar

I'm using this custom function to get the default avatar from my server instead of gravatar:

```
if(!function_exists('custom_avatar')){
    function custom_avatar($avatar_defaults){
        $new_default_icon = 'http://localhost/gv/wp-content/images/mystery-man.png';
        $avatar_defaults[$new_default_icon] = 'Custom Avatar';
        return $avatar_defaults;
    }
    add_filter('avatar_defaults','custom_avatar');
}
```

but the custom avatar is not showing up, when I view source code then the `src` of the image look like this:

```
http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/a432e8915b383edd8d25c2a4fd5a6995?s=32&d=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fgv%2Fwp-content%2Fimages%2Fmystery-man.png%3Fs%3D32&r=G&forcedefault=1
```

Why does my image src relative to gravatar here? How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/159482

Comment: Whereever you want display your custom avatar, do something like this in that template of your active them: <div id="author-avatar">
       
<?php _e('<img src="'.get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory').'/images/admin-avatar.jpg" width="48" height="48" alt="' . get_the_author() . '" />');?>
       </div><!-- #author-avatar -->

Answer (score 0):

just use the function get_avatar, $default is for your custom default.

```
<?php echo get_avatar( $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt, $args ); ?>
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_avatar

Answer (score 0):

Just add this in your functions.php file (Image URL must be complete). Then go to the gravatar choice section and choose the new avatar.

```
/*** Change default gravatar */
add_filter( 'avatar_defaults', 'new_gravatar' );
function new_gravatar ($avatar_defaults) {
$myavatar = 'https://example.com/image.webp';
$avatar_defaults[$myavatar] = "Default Gravatar";
return $avatar_defaults;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To display a custom default avatar instead of Gravatar in Wp using a filter hook, you can use the `avatar_defaults` filter hook

```
// Add custom default avatar
function custom_default_avatar( $avatar_defaults ) {
    $custom_avatar_url = 'URL_TO_YOUR_CUSTOM_AVATAR_IMAGE'; // Replace this with the URL of your custom avatar image
    $avatar_defaults['custom_avatar'] = 'Custom Avatar'; // Add a label for your custom avatar
    return $avatar_defaults;
}
add_filter( 'avatar_defaults', 'custom_default_avatar' );

// Function to replace Gravatar with custom default avatar
function replace_default_avatar( $avatar, $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt ) {
    $custom_avatar_url = 'URL_TO_YOUR_CUSTOM_AVATAR_IMAGE'; // Replace this with the URL of your custom avatar image
    $custom_avatar = "<img alt='{$alt}' src='{$custom_avatar_url}' class='avatar avatar-{$size} photo' height='{$size}' width='{$size}' />";
    return $custom_avatar;
}
add_filter( 'get_avatar', 'replace_default_avatar', 10, 5 );
```